# How can i send the value of a modal text input into another page?

Tags: php, html, laravel, bootstrap-modal

Hello i'm using laravel php and I don't get the value of my input in the page where i send it 
when I dd($numexam) on my controller function it show me that it's null.
I'm a beginer with laravel and php and programming

```
public function updatenote(Request $request){
  $num=$request->input('numexam');
  dd($num);
  $exam = Exam::find($num);
  $note=$request->input('note');
  $exam->note=$note;
  $exam->save();
  return Redirect::back();
}
```

This is my routes web.php

```
    Route::get('/ajout', 'ExamsController@create');
    Route::post('/ajout', 'ExamsController@store')->name('exam.import');
    Route::get('/notemodifier', 'ExamsController@updatenote');

<!-- Button trigger modal -->
    <td>
    <button value="{{$verification->numexam}}" 
     onClick="document.getElementById('numexam').innerHTML=this.value" 
     type="button" class="btn btn-light" data-toggle="modal" data- 
     target="#exampleModalCenter">
     Update mark
     </button>
     </td>
```

My view elements:

```
<form action="/notemodifier" method="get">
  <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLongTitle">Modifier la note</h5>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
      </div>

      <div class="modal-body">
        <center>
        <label>Taper la nouvelle note:</label>
        <input required type="text" name="note">
        </center>
        <input type="hidden" name="numexam" id="numexam">
      </div>

      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Fermer</button>
        <button  type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Modifier</button>
      </div>
    </div>
</form>

  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: DId you tried with "$num = $request->get('numexam');" ?

Comment: yes and it's giving me null too

Comment: The problem could be that the input hidden doesn't have the "value" attribute...

Comment: No because when I inscpect the view in the browser it's having the value

Answer (score 0):

```
 Route::get('/notemodifier', 'ExamsController@updatenote');
```

change it to

```
 Route::post('/notemodifier', 'ExamsController@updatenote');
```

in your controller

```
 public function updatenote(Request $request){
   $input = $request->all();
   dd($input);
   $exam = Exam::find($input['numexam']);
   $note=$input('note');
   $exam->note=$note;
   $exam->save();
   return Redirect::back();
 }
```